# Automatically discover composer packages

Tags: php, json, composer-php

I'm wondering what the best way (if there is a way) for an application to auto-discover [relevant] PHP "packages" installed by Composer.

**My use case specific scenario:**

I have a PHP app that includes my "framework" (for lack of a better word). This framework brings some basic functionality (routing, admin etc).

I'm slowly building in more advanced functionality, say, a blog module. This module is entirely self contained in it's own directory (but obviously has dependencies on the framework).

I'd like this blog module to be a self contained Composer package, so that I can selectively require the package in my app's root composer.json file.

Now, I need for the framework to know that it's there so that it can, for example, set the routing correctly and load up any admin functionality that the module requires.

**What I've thought so far:**

I'm relatively experienced in PHP, but "proper" OOP and autoloading is a little bit beyond my knowledge at the moment, so please forgive if there are inbuilt functions to do this. I don't even know what terms to Google!

I have thought I could maybe read the installed.json file which composer puts at `vendor/composer/installed.php` but I'm not sure how to set up my packages (e.g. `blog`) so they announce what they are. I'd like to future proof it so that I'm not looking for known module names (or regexing vendor or package names), but rather looking for packages to say "hey framework, I know you! You can use me!"

Maybe I can somehow instruct Composer (through the package's composer.json file) to stick in an arbitrary key/value pair in installed.json?

Any suggestions welcome, or directions as to what sort of Googling I should be doing.

Comment: Welcome to [StackOverflow!](http://stackoverflow.com) Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Answer (score 1):

Oh welcome to the world of managing dependencies on your framework.

I have some experience with [auraphp](http://auraphp.com), where we dealt with similar issue. You can read the blog post [Composer-Assisted Two-Stage Configuration](http://auraphp.com/blog/2014/04/07/two-stage-config/) .

So what we finally ended-up adding https://github.com/auraphp/Aura.Web/blob/a3870d1a16ecd3ab6c4807165ac5196384da62cd/composer.json#L26-L36 these lines in the packages that need to understand to load by the framework.

You can also see how this bundle can also get autoloaded with the configurations.

in your `composer.json`

https://github.com/harikt/Aura.Asset_Bundle/blob/6ea787979390e69bf6ecb1e33ce00ed90f306e2f/composer.json#L21-L27

and the `config/Common.php` ( https://github.com/harikt/Aura.Asset_Bundle/blob/223126cedb460e486c4f0b242719c96c14be5385/config/Common.php ) , note we have other development modes also. For a detailed look check https://github.com/auraphp/Aura.Web_Project or https://github.com/auraphp/Aura.Framework_Project

Hope that helps a bit to look into the code and work on your own solution.

Comment: Thanks, that's actually very helpful - and along the same lines as the route I was looking at in the first place.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped you.